# Best practice for multiple services using Prisma ORM with the same database?

Tags: postgresql, prisma, next-auth

I am using next-auth for authentication, which handles auth with users, accounts, and sessions tables in the data base. I also have a separate server which connects to the same database and needs to access those users (but also do other things that the next side of my app doesn't need to touch).

I want to use Prisma ORM on both of these services which both interact with the same underlying database. What is the best practices for keeping schemas in sync? Is it ok to just manually copy over the schema.prisma files and migrations over and npx prisma generate?